# Python script for segregating column by flag values and saving to two files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data file containing four columns.

test.txt file :

id | addr  | value | flag|

:--|:----- |-------|-----|

300|  275  |   5   |  0  |

300|  766  |  15   |  1

300|  276  |   3   |  1

300|  248  |   6   |  1

300|  267  |   11  |  1

508|205    |   12  |  0

508|201    |   12  |  1

301|32     |   3   |  0

301|44     |   4   |  1

301|32     |   2   |   0

I need to segregate the second column values based on the flag value of the fourth column and save those to two separate files.

required output:
file:1

### id  |  addr(f=0)

300 |  275
508 |  205
301 |  32
file:2

### id  | addr(f=1)

300 |766
300 |276
300 |248
300 |267
508 |201
301 |44

I am very new to python and so far I have done the following.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: {0} filename\n".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit()

fn = sys.argv[1]
sys.stderr.write("reading " + fn + "...\n")

# Initialize dictionaries (or hash id)
list_id = {}

fin = open(fn,"r")
for line in fin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    f = line.split("|")
    id = f[0]
    addr = f[1]
    flag = f[3]

fin.close()
```

Need your suggestion to complete the program.
Thanks in advance for your kind help.

The real glimpse of Data :

[image]

Comment: it would be really helpful if you also add an expected output to the question :), could you?

Comment: @DamianLattenero He already did.

Comment: Also, your input text looks like it has the pipe character `|` as a separator, but you use a tab `\t` in your code. Can you update either the input or the code, or specify that the text file is a TSV file?

Comment: @Bit haha that's true, I didn't understood sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a variant using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
from csv import reader, writer

with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    rows = reader(file, delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True)
    with open('file1.txt', 'w') as file1, open('file2.txt', 'w') as file2:
        writer1 = writer(file1, delimiter='|')
        writer2 = writer(file2, delimiter='|')
        for row in rows:

            try:
                flag = int(row[3])
            except IndexError:
                # row does has less than 4 elements, next row!
                print('row too short!', row)
                continue
            except ValueError:
                # if this is not an integer, next row!
                print('row[3] not an int!', row[3])
                continue

            if flag == 0:
                writer1.writerow(row[:2])  # write the first 2 entries only
            elif flag == 1:
                writer2.writerow(row[:2])
            else:
                print('flag not in (0, 1)!', flag)
```

---

for your updated (and different from the original) input, changing the reader to

```
rows = reader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am getting the following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mithu\Desktop\test\ex01 - Copy.py", line 14, in <module>
    flag = int(row[3])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: yeah, noticed the empty lines in your input file. should be fixed now.

Comment: Great !! after the edit in the code for the index error the code worked perfectly! Genius ! Thanks a  lot!

Comment: Hey, sorry to get back to you again on this! The code worked well for the above input. but after testing it to a bigger test file it stopped working again. there is no error and file1 and file2 is generated, but no sorted output inside the file.It also stopped working on the old test data as well !!!!! Your suggestion requested.

Comment: 70279  442 1700000000000 0 
70280  70280 5000000000 1
70281  70281 5000000000 1
70288  70288 5000000000 0
70288  70288 5000000000 1
Consider above as the new test data... Do I have to change the delimiter in the previous code?- Thanks

Comment: yes, `rows = reader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)` should work. the script will do nothing if `row[3]` does not exist or can not be cast to an integer or is not either `0` or `1`. make sure the flag is read from the correct column.

Comment: No error, but The problem is When I put blank in the delimiter like this: rows = reader(file, delimiter= '  ', skipinitialspace=True),  the output files are not showing any results. The test file I have has around 32 Million data and the ID and addr numbers start from 1 to 25 Million. So the spaces between fields varies.How to solve this problem?

Comment: Just updated the question with a screenshot so that you can understand ... If I paste here in comments the data format keeps changing... Please let me know if its fine for you. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the data :                                                                              
451318  451318 4514000000 1
451318  451318 5000000 1
451318  451318 4520000000 0
451319  451319 4514000000 0
451319  451319 4508000000 1
451319  451319 5000000 1
451320  860 4502000000 1
451320  860 5000000 1
451320  860 4508000000 0

Comment: ok, updated the answer. this works for your newly given input.

Comment: Following output msg : row too short! ['70416\t13558\t5000000000\t0'] row too short! ['451828', '451828\t4171000000', '\t1'] row too short!  ['451828','451828\t4177000000', '\t0']  row too short! ['451829', '451829\t30000000', '\t0']row too short! ['451829', '451829\t11000000', '\t1'] row too short! ['451829', '451829\t19000000', '\t1'] row too short! ['451830', '451830\t150000000', '\t1'] row too short! ['451830', '451830\t50000000', '\t0']  row too short! ['451830', '451830\t1000000\t\t0']
row too short! ['451830', '451830\t1000000', '\t0']

Comment: your file seems to have tabs `\t` and spaces mixed. best clean that up before running the script.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the if-else now.

```
to_write = id + "\t" + addr

if flag == 0:
    # write out the "to_write" to file number 1
elif flag == 1:
    # write out the "to_write" to file number 2
```

Comment: Please assist me to understand with some code and a bit of explanation.  Thanks a ton!